# CS50 greedy algorithm

Tags: c, cs50

I just started C programming with cs50.

I tried to do the problem set about the greedy algorithm but can't seem to find the bug. My code is below.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main (void)
{

int count = 0;

printf("how much is the change?: ");

float change = get_float();

while(change < 0)
{
   printf("change is to be more than 0");
   change = get_float();
 }

int amount = lroundf(change*100);

while(amount > 0)
{
  if ((amount-25) >= 25)
  {
      amount  =  amount - 25;
      count++;
  }

  else if ((amount-10) >= 10)
  {
      amount =  amount - 10;
      count++;
  }

  else if ((amount-5) >= 5)
  {
      amount = amount -5;
      count++;
  }

  else if((amount-1) >= 1)
  {
      amount = amount -1;
      count ++;
      break;
  }

  else
  {
   printf("you have no change \n");   
  }
  }
  printf("your number of coins is %i\n", count);

  }
```

When I input my change as 1, I am given back 8 coins. Can't seem to find where the bug is. Can anyone help me?

Comment: did you check [cs50.se]?

Comment: `>= 25` --> `>= 0` and so on. or simply `(amount-25) >= 25` --> `amount >= 25`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you could try running your program with values for `change` that return simple answers, like 1 coin, using, for example, `change = 0.25`. If that works, then you should start trying with some few coins, repeating one type, like you did with `1.00`, or joining a few types, like `0.06` . And after that, try big numbers and values with higher floating inaccuracy, like `4.10`. Following this should lead you to your answers.

If, after trying that, you still can't find the problem, then here is the answer: the problem is with the `if`/`else if` expressions. When you are trying to count the quarters, for example, the `(amount-25) >= 25` doesn't work properly. You're trying to take away a quarter while `amount` is bigger or equal to 25, but your code just do that until it gets to less than 50. Developing your expression may help you see it: `(amount-25) >= 25` -> `(amount-25) + 25 >= 25 + 25` -> `amount >= 50`.

Another problem you may find is with that `break` statement. It might get out from the loop earlier than expected. If you try running numbers like `0.04` and `0.03` you'll see the count stuck at `1`. After removing the first penny, the code breaks out of the loop leaving `amount` still bigger than 0. `break`s make it harder to see when the code is getting out of the loop and that's why many programmers recommend avoiding it whenever possible.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed answers, helped me alot.